# vimperator, how to set qmark differently based on operating system?

Tags: javascript, firefox, vimperator

How can I achieve below with [vimperator](http://vimperator.org/vimperator.html) (possibly some javascript)?

- on windows 10

  qmark d file:///E:/somedirectory
- on linux

  qmark d file:///home/username/somedirectory

what kind of code should be put into my `.vimperatorrc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this

```
js if(options["shell"]=="/bin/bash"){quickmarks.add("d", "file:///home/username/somedirectory")}else{quickmarks.add("d","file:///E:/somedirectory")};
```

Explanation: If /bin/bash is your shell you're running linux. If you're running windows this will probably be cmd.exe (It is on windows 7, I can't test on windows 10 unfortunately). The vimperator internal function quickmarks.add is then used to add the desired quickmark. If there are problems, try

```
echo options["shell"]
```

in the vimperator shell and then change the line accordingly.

Comment: Also, could I find something -- eg, doc -- more comprehensive about that (`options["shell"]`) anywhere?? I am interested in vimperator and know a little about js&DOM stuff. Also use vim regularly, if that matter.

Comment: I don't know about any documentation but the source code is very comprehensible. In this case the relevant file is common/content/io.js from the vimperator-labs repository.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see that file.